# How to connect to Samba SMB2/SMB3 with domain authentication from Ubuntu 16.04 using GUI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I can't connect to samba after blocking SMB1 protocol.
Early, I just click in Nautilus to "Connect to Server" and inputted smb://mySambaHost/. Now, I can get connected with this way.
`Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out`

I tried installing smbclient, but I can only connect to server whith no-friendly command (for me):
`/usr/bin/smbclient \\\\my_server\\shared_folder -U WINDOWS_DOMAIN/WINDOWS_DOMAIN_USERNAME -W WINDOWS_WORKGROUP -mSMB3` and every time input password.
That is, I infer that the server and login/password are working

I tried mounted samba share_folder, but could not do it (I don't now how).
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=WINDOWS_DOMAIN/WINDOWS_DOMAIN_USERNAME,password=WINDOWS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD,rw //myServer/ /media/windowsshare`
`/media/windowsshare` is exist

Can some help me to easely get acces to samba share folders using SMB2/SMB3 protocol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the version (vers=3.0):

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=WINDOWS_DOMAIN/WINDOWS_DOMAIN_USERNAME,password=WINDOWS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD,rw,vers=3.0 //myServer/ /media/windowsshare /media/windowsshare
```

You could also try with `2.0` & `2.1`